# Matplotlib editing legend labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I modify the labels of a plot with `plt.legend([some labels])` and then I call `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` I get back the old labels.

Here a simple example:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.plot([1,2,3], label='A')
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f60749be310>]

In [3]: plt.plot([2,3,4], label='B')
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f60749f1850>]

In [4]: ax = plt.gca()

In [5]: l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

In [6]: l
Out[6]:
([<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f60749be310>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f60749f1850>],
 [u'A', u'B'])

In [7]: plt.legend(['C', 'D'])  ### This correctly modifies the legend to show 'C' and 'D', but then ...
Out[7]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7f6081dce190>

In [10]: l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

In [11]: l
Out[11]:
([<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f60749be310>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f60749f1850>],
 [u'A', u'B'])
```

At this point I have no idea how to retrieve the list of shown labels, i.e. `['C', 'D']`.
What am I missing? What other method should I use?

To give a bit more context, what I'm trying to do is to plot a pandas dataframe, modify the legend to add some information and then plot another dataframe on the same axes and repeat the same procedure with the labels.
In order to do that, the second time I need to modify PART of the labels in the legend and keep the rest unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing what is suggested in the function doc of [`plt.legend`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) accomplishes what you wanted.

> Signature: plt.legend(*args, **kwargs) Docstring: Places a legend on
>   the axes.
>
> To make a legend for lines which already exist on the axes (via plot
>   for instance), simply call this function with an iterable of strings,
>   one for each legend item. For example::
>
> ```
> ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
> ax.legend(['A simple line'])
> ```
>
> However, in order to keep the "label" and the legend element instance
>   together, it is preferable to specify the label either at artist
>   creation, or by calling the
>   :meth:`~matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label` method on the artist::
>
> ```
> line, = ax.plot([1, 2, 3], label='Inline label')
> # Overwrite the label by calling the method.
> line.set_label('Label via method')
> ax.legend()
> ```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line1, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='A')
line2, = plt.plot([2,3,4], label='B')

ax = plt.gca()
l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
print(l)

line1.set_label("C")
line2.set_label("D")
ax.legend()

l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
print(l)
plt.show()

>>([<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000000000A399EB8>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000008A67710>], ['A', 'B'])
>>([<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000000000A399EB8>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000008A67710>], ['C', 'D'])
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works, but I have to say that the default behavior of `plt.legend` is quite puzzling. Is there a reason why this command should give you the possibility of changing the legend without propagating the changes to the underlying objects?

In the use case I presented at the end, the solution you propose makes for a very convoluted code.

I waited a bit before accepting to see if there were alternatives, I'm accepting it now.

Comment: They may have a reason for why it behaves like this, it may just be "legacy" reasons ^^ You'd have to ask the developers to get a clear answer i guess